# If I have two discs for Minecraft on the XBOX, will it get confused?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

At the moment we have 1 copy, and each child has their own worlds. However, one of them owns the disc, which causes fights.

So, can my children have separate copies of the same Minecraft game? Will the XBOX get confused?

Comment: This sounds more like a family management problem than a gaming problem...

Comment: Getting a digital copy will avoid this issue

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted so much. I have never used an Xbox and I have no idea how it handles disks versus accounts, so I imagine an unexperienced person may have a legitimate question like that.

Answer (score 10):

The disc only contains information to run the games. The saves are kept separately (i.e. are not stored on the disc, but in external storage), and belong to each user. So if you had 2 copies of the game, it would make no difference to your setup.

So in other words, Bob signs into his profile. He plays Minecraft. He creates his owns worlds, plays his own games etc. When Bob's finished, John signs into his own profile. He has *his own* worlds, and has *no access* to any of Bob's worlds, unless they play split screen - together.

To clarify, split screen allows players to play on the same console, but there will be a "primary" account, and the other (up to 3 others) will be the "secondary" accounts. In this situation, the "primary" account is the one that started the game. The players will then be using the save games of that "primary" account.

> Splitscreen is a Console Edition-exclusive feature that allows up to four players to play on one screen at the same time.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splitscreen)

So all in all, getting a separate copy of the game will have no effect at all.

Comment: Note that this will still only allow one child to play at a time. If they both want to play minecraft at the same time, they will need two XBoxes and two copies of the game. If you'd rather not buy another XBox, you can also buy minecraft for PC.

Answer (score 0):

there is a splitscreen version but if you only want one person to play at once, it would work.
To settle any confusion you can create 2 seperate accounts on the xbox's memory unit (whichever one you use) and they cant possibly see each others worlds

so basically with two seperate profiles the disc is useless.